# Angular conditional attributes

Tags: angularjs

I study AngularJS, now try to add an attribute based on one (or multiple) condition(s).

But this code (**[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/EmdpMo?editors=1011)**) doesn't seem to work:

```js
function myController($scope) {
  console.log("start");
  $scope.item = { myBool: false };
  $scope.myClick = function(e) {
    var myHref = angular.element(e.delegateTarget).data(href);
    console.log(myHref);
  };
}
```

```css
.test{background: lightblue; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div np-app ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="test" 
       data-href="{undefined: !item.myBool, 'http://yes.com': item.myBool}" 
       ng-click="myClick($event);console.log('end');">click & see the console</div>
</div>
```

actually the `data-href` attribute should not be defined, as `myBool == false`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, updated a little bit the Vanojx1 answer to:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    console.log("start");
    $scope.item = { myBool: false };
    $scope.myClick = function(e) {
      $scope.item.myBool = !$scope.item.myBool;
      console.log(angular.element(e.target).attr("href"));
      console.log(angular.element(e.target).attr("noarg"));     
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="test" ng-attr-href="{{item.myBool? 'http://yes.com' : undefined}}" ng-click="myClick($event)">
    click & see the console
  </div>
</div>
```

Important improvements:

- updated the Angular version to be `> 1.3` (actually I used an ancient one);
- used the `ng-attr-xxx` attribute that is **removed** (the attribute itself, not just its value) if its value estimated to `undefined`;

Answer (score 3):

Use [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) for that:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    console.log("start");
    $scope.item = {
      myBool: false
    };
    $scope.myClick = function(e) {
      $scope.item.myBool = !$scope.item.myBool;
      console.log(angular.element(e.target).attr("href"));
    };
  });
```

```css
.test{background: lightblue; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="test" href="{{item.myBool ? 'http://yes.com' : undefined}}" ng-click="myClick($event)">
    click & see the console
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why does the "{aV: aC, bV: bC, cV: cC...}" not work?

Comment: thanks for your help, unfortunately the code does not work as expected, because adds an attribute anyway, try to add `console.log(angular.element(e.target).attr("inexistent"));`

Comment: not really, it estimates its value. I found an answer based on your code bellow ;) thanks!